# How to get wikipedia categories on Android application

Tags: android, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I make the Android Application now. 
I want to implement the method as below:

- judge if there is an article of "key word"
- if there is, return categories.
- if there is not or a category is "Disambiguation pages", return null.

For example, if key word is "New_york", 
The method should return one Array that contains "New York", "Former British colonies", "States of the United States".

if key word is "Hogehogehoge", the method should return null.

How can I implement them?
There is API for PHP and so on, but I cannot find for Android. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try this for a start. http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MediaWiki API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) is not “for PHP”, it can be used from any language. To help you create the query, you can use [the API Sandbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aApiSandbox).

Specifically for your query, [you need to use the `query` action with `prop=categories`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aApiSandbox#action=query&prop=categories&format=json&clshow=!hidden&cllimit=10&titles=New_York), the final query looks like (possibly with `format=xml` if you want the response in XML instead of JSON):

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=categories&format=json&clshow=!hidden&cllimit=10&titles=New+York

It's also possible there is some library for Android that would make this easier for you, but I can't help you with that.

Comment: Thank you for your advance. 
I'd like to use Media Wiki API. 
How can I embed API to Java source cord?

If you know some tips, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you, I could utilize MediaWiki API.